# Multiple Text-Column Index

Tags: postgresql

I'm exploring how postgres works in different circumstances. My questions concerns multi-column indexes. Let's say I create and populate the following table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS perf_test;

create table perf_test(id int, reason text, annotation text);

insert into perf_test(id, reason, annotation)
select s.id, md5(random()::text), null)
from generate_series(1,10000000) as s(id)
order by random();

-- do this separately to avoid the same values for both columns
UPDATE perf_test
SET annotation = md5(random()::text)
```

If I run a query such as:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT *
FROM  perf_test
WHERE reason LIKE 'bc%' AND annotation LIKE 'ab%';
```

I get a parallel sequential scan, not surprisingly. If I build an index for both columns:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_perf_test_reason_annotation
ON perf_test(reason,annotation);
```

and then run the same query again, I get the same problem: a sequential scan. Why the planner doesn't want to switch to the index scan? The result consists of about 100 records (not so many I guess). I tried other chars getting just several records but still, it did that with a sequential scan. Why it doesn't want to use index even when the result consists of a couple of rows?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the execution plan (as formatted text)

Comment: re-analyze the table? with so many few rows the cost may not be worth it to use the index.

Comment: duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188344/text-index-using-text-pattern-ops-with-utf-8-vs-default-operator-class-with-c/188363#188363